# StateSave issue in Datatables.net during postbacks

Tags: javascript, c#, datatable

I am using Datatables.net with huge records. At the end of each row i have a server side asp:button that brings a popup to update user information from that row. When I click it, a postback occurs and the entire Datatable is redrawn. I am using savestate but I want to clear the state at every postback, so that when I click a row button, the postback does not take me back to the last page i was at when i clicked the button. Below is my code so far:

```
       function fnClickRedraw() {
           var table;
           $(document).ready(function () {
               if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
                   table = $('#example').DataTable();



               }

               else {

                   table = $('#example').DataTable(

                         {

                             "bSort": false

                         }

                       );

               }

           });

       }

       </script>
```

Comment: function fnClickRedraw() {
           var table;
           $(document).ready(function () {
               if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
                   table = $('#example').DataTable();



               }

               else {

                   table = $('#example').DataTable(

                         {
"bSaveState": true,
                             "bSort": false

                         }

                       );

               }

           });

       }

       </script>

Comment: your question is not cleared....you should update your question with details.